# How to minimize time in searching on big files

Tags: unix

I am looking for better solution for below mentioned code in Unix.

```
cat $FILE_PROC | while read LINE
  do
    SEG_NBR=`echo $LINE | cut -c 1-1`

       if [ "${SEG_NBR}" == "3" ] ; then
               echo "Logical level header is identified"
               #COUNT_DETAIL_SEG=0

       elif [ "${SEG_NBR}" == "4" ] ; then
                   COUNT_DETAIL_SEG=`expr ${COUNT_DETAIL_SEG} + 1`
                   SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS=${COUNT_DETAIL_SEG}
                   echo "Sum of detail records is $SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS"

       fi
```

In above mentioned code, Cat command looks for certain SEG_NBR in each line of file.
I am facing trouble in execution of this script in big files(e.g of 565656) lines.

Is there any better way of executing above portion of script with same results

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using grep?

```
grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

Comment: Are you saying that i should redirect different patterns to different files so as to make small files?

Comment: if you're looking for SEG_NBR in a line of a file you can use `grep SEG_NBR filenamehere.txt` and it will give you all of the lines that have SEG_NBR in it.

Comment: SEG_NBR appears in each line of file but the thing is that we do not know whether SEG_NBR is 3 or 4 or 5.So are you trying to say that i should direct different SEG_NBR patterns to different files that will help in creation of small files thereby making the search easy?

Comment: Yes that would work, If you can post an example of a few lines I could perhaps give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

your use of command-substitution for each line processed is very expensive for processing a file quickly.

While you haven't provided sample input or expected output, I think an awk script is a much better (faster processing) solution for this problem. Here is a general guide based on the logic embedded in your code.

```
awk '{
    if (substr($0,1,1) == "3" ) {  
       print "Logical level header is identified"
    }
    else if (substr($0,1,1) == "4") { 
       count_detail_seg++
       sum_of_detail_rcds=count_detail_seg
       print "Sum of detail records is " sum_of_detail_rcds
    }
 }' $FILE_PROC
```

Note that your code

```
COUNT_DETAIL_SEG=`expr ${COUNT_DETAIL_SEG} + 1`
```

is incrementing COUNT_DETAIL_SEG by 1 each time you match "4".

```
count_detail_seg++
```

is the short-cut version of that expression in awk.

Why are you doing

```
 SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS=${COUNT_DETAIL_SEG}
```

?  This just duplicates the value  you've already stored in COUNT_DETAIL_SEG

If you want a true SUM_OF_DETAILS, you have to identify the position in the file that has the record value you want to create a SUM for.  If you line of data looks like

```
 4<T>ABC Company<T>12345<T>USD<T>99.99
```

Then as a `tab` delimited record where `99.99` represents the value you want to sum, this is the fifth (5th) field on the file and I would sum values with this

```
       sum_of_detail_rcds+=$5
```

In you next question, please include a small set of sample data, and the required output from that same data. Also include what your current output looks like and a copy/paste of any error messages you are getting.

IHTH

Comment: what is $o is this solution?

Comment: that is the "whole line" of data, note that is a zero char `0`, not a lower-case o char.

Comment: i got your point but suppose i need to cut characters 16-25 like as mentioned below TOT_NUM_OF_DTL_RCDS_FILE=`echo "${LINE}"| cut -c 33-40` and LINE is (cat $FILE_PROC | while read LINE ) then how to take care of this using awk

Comment: `substr($0,33,8)` equals `cut -c 33-40`.  `awk` is a line-oriented  utility. For a block of code like I have defined `{ ....... }` awk reads one line of data, which available in `$0`, (and $1 has the first field, ...etc). When all steps in the `{ block }` have been processed then a new line of data is read in, and the process starts over again. So `$0` will have the same value as your `$LINE` variable. Good luck.

Comment: Can you let me know how to handle this   if [ "${SEG_NBR}" == "6" ] ; then
                 echo "Logical level trailer is identified"

                     LOGICAL_FILE=`expr ${LOGICAL_FILE} + 1`
                     ##DEFECT 1724 Starts here
                     #TOT_NUM_OF_DTL_RCDS_FILE=`echo "${LINE}"| cut -c 2-6`
                      TOT_NUM_OF_DTL_RCDS_FILE=`echo "${LINE}"| cut -c 16-25`

Comment: sorry, I've given you an outline of what features to use and answered your initial question. I recommend that you add debugging `print "#dbg:seg_num=" seg_num` type statements to test your theories about how to solve the rest of your coding problem. Good luck.